# How to refresh without cache on Chrome iOS

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser-cache

I'm developing a website for fun and to learn and I'm trying it on my iPad too running Chrome.

Every time I have to make some changes to the CSS, though, I would have had to clear the cache going into Settings->History and cleaning it manually.

Is there an easier way?

Comment: Can you just open a private browsing tab and each time you make a change, just close it and reopen it?

Comment: Unfortunately the page needs a login with Google to be accessible, so it would mean inserting my password every time I have to force a file to be downloaded again

Answer (score 0):

If you guys have a keyboard connected to your iPad (I personally have the Logitech Type +) you can hit

**Fn+Cmd+R**

on your bluetooth keyboard and it will do the trick.

Already saved my life a couple times.

Comment: This method does not help people who do not have access to the said peripheral, which I expect is a fair amount of the user-base.